# How to Implement Sticky header with fast scroll in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fastscroll, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want to enable fast scrolling in my sticky header recyclerview

I have below type of recyclerview with sticky header

[image]

I'm using https://github.com/Codewaves/Sticky-Header-Grid for sticky header view implementation now i want enable fast scrolling in my recyclerview

I'm using below code

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rv_clue"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      tools:visibility="gone"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:paddingTop="8dp"
      android:paddingBottom="88dp"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      />
```

Adapter code

```
    class ResultsAdapter(private val context: Context) : StickyHeaderGridAdapter(), FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter {
  private val labels: MutableList<List<String>> = mutableListOf()
  private val sectionLabel: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()


  fun setData(sectionList: List<String>, list: List<List<String>>) {
    sectionLabel.addAll(sectionList)
    labels.addAll(list)
  }

  override fun getSectionCount(): Int {
    return labels.size
  }

  override fun getSectionItemCount(section: Int): Int {
    return labels[section].size
  }

  override fun onCreateHeaderViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, headerType: Int): HeaderViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout.cell_header, parent, false)
    return MyHeaderViewHolder(view)
  }

  override fun onCreateItemViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, itemType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout.cell_item, parent, false)
    return MyItemViewHolder(view)
  }

  override fun onBindHeaderViewHolder(viewHolder: HeaderViewHolder, section: Int) {
    val holder = viewHolder as MyHeaderViewHolder
    val label: String = if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(sectionLabel[section])) {
      if (sectionLabel[section] === "1") {
        sectionLabel[section] + " Letter"
      } else {
        sectionLabel[section] + " Letters"
      }
    } else {
      sectionLabel[section]
    }
    holder.labelView.text = label
  }

  override fun onBindItemViewHolder(viewHolder: ItemViewHolder, section: Int, position: Int) {
    val holder = viewHolder as MyItemViewHolder
    val label = labels[section][position]
    holder.labelView.text = label
    if (label === context.getString(string.add_words)) {
      holder.labelView.setOnClickListener { v: View? -> }
    } else if (label === context.getString(string.search_more)) {
      holder.labelView.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
        holder.labelView.text = context.getString(string.searching_more)
        // MainActivity.getInstance().searchApiCall("", true)
      }
    }
  }


  class MyHeaderViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : HeaderViewHolder(itemView) {
    var labelView: TextView

    init {
      labelView = itemView.findViewById(id.label)
    }
  }

  class MyItemViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : ItemViewHolder(itemView) {
    var labelView: TextView

    init {
      labelView = itemView.findViewById(id.label)
    }
  }

  override fun getSectionName(position: Int): String {
    return position.toString()
  }
}
```

Till now i have tried many library from github and event tried many stackoverflow answer but still i'm not able to enable fast scrolling in recyclerview

I have tried below answer till now

- [How to use fastScrollEnabled in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370246/how-to-use-fastscrollenabled-in-recyclerview)
- [How to add a fast-scroller to the RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview)
- [Fast Scrolling on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851667/fast-scrolling-on-recyclerview)
- https://medium.com/android-news/fast-scrolling-with-recyclerview-2b89d4574688
- https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll

can anybody help me to implement fast scrolling in recyclerview

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated